# how to validate the min and max value on select specific product from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user selects the specific product from the option box I want to put validation in width text box that user only enter a value between 10 to 200

I am done with getting selected value but not able to validate it properly

I also use HTML5 attributes min and max but not working.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#product').change(function() {
    if ($('#product').val() == 'Copper flat') {
      if ($('#width').val() >= 10 && $('#width').val() <= 200) {
        alert("Value must be between 10 to 200")
      }
    } else if ($('#product').val() == 'Fabricated Copper Busbar') {

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="product" id="product" class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Product type</option>
  <option value="Copper flat">Copper flat</option>
  <option value="Fabricated Copper Busbar">Fabricated Copper Busbar</option>
  <option value="Fabricated aluminium Busbar">Fabricated aluminium Busbar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `min` and `max` values of an `input` use jQuery's `prop()` method. Also note that you can DRY up the logic by putting the values associated with each `option` in `data` attributes on the element which can easily be read when the `change` event occurs. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $width = $('#width');

  $('#product').change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $width.prop({
      min: $selected.data('min'),
      max: $selected.data('max')
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <select name="product" id="product" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Product type</option>
    <option value="Copper flat" data-min="10" data-max="200">Copper flat</option>
    <option value="Fabricated Copper Busbar" data-min="100" data-max="2000">Fabricated Copper Busbar</option>
    <option value="Fabricated aluminium Busbar" data-min="50" data-max="75">Fabricated aluminium Busbar</option>
  </select>

  Width: <input type="number" id="width" required />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, @rory I will accept this as an answer in 2 min

Comment: But, What if I want to add more conditions on a selected product means I want to hide other text boxes also.

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555515/how-can-i-use-two-data-min-and-data-max-attribute-in-single-tag

can you help with this too? Thanks in advance :)