# how can i use two data-min and data-max attribute in single tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate the width and thickness of the product on a selected product I am done with width but confuse with the thickness.

like, I want to validate the width between 10 to 200 and also want to validate the thickness between 1 to 30. So I manage to validate the width but confuse in managing thickness. here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  var $width = $('#width');
  var $thickness = $('#thickness');

  $('#product').change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $width.prop({
      min: $selected.data('min'),
      max: $selected.data('max')
    });
    $thickness.prop({
      min: $selected.data('min'),
      max: $selected.data('max')
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <select name="product" id="product" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Product type</option>
    <option value="Copper flat" data-min-width="10" data-max-width="200" data-min-thickness="1" data-max-thickness="20">Copper flat</option>
    <option value="Fabricated Copper Busbar" data-min="100" data-max="2000">Fabricated Copper Busbar</option>
    <option value="Fabricated aluminium Busbar" data-min="50" data-max="75">Fabricated aluminium Busbar</option>
  </select>

  Width: <input type="number" id="width" required />
  
  thickness: <input type="number" id="thickness" required />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `data-min-width=10 data-min-thickness=1 ...`

Comment: I will try this and let u know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add more specific data attributes:

`data-min-width`, `data-max-width`, `data-min-thickness`, `data-max-thickness`

Comment: Please check my edited question.! let me know if I am doing some mistake.

Comment: @BhushanPatil `$selected.data('min')` should be `$selected.data('min-width')` for width and `$selected.data('min-thickness')` for thickness. Same for max

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code, it seems that you are trying to read max and min width as well as thickness data attributes from the selected option but you are just reading 'min' and 'max' instead of 'min-width', 'min-thickness' etc.

See below code

```
$(function() {
  var $width = $('#width');
  var $thickness = $('#thickness');

  $('#product').change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $width.prop({
      min: $selected.data('min-width'),
      max: $selected.data('max-width')
    });
    $thickness.prop({
      min: $selected.data('min-thickness'),
      max: $selected.data('max-thickness')
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use data attribute like data-min-width, data-max-width, data-min-thickness, data-max-thickness, and get this using attr property of jquery.

```js
$(function() {
  var $width = $('#width');
  var $thickness = $('#thickness');

  $('#product').change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $width.prop({
      min: $selected.attr('data-min-width'),
      max: $selected.attr('data-max-width')
    });
    $thickness.prop({
       min: $selected.attr('data-min-thickness'),
       max: $selected.attr('data-max-thickness')
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <select name="product" id="product" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Product type</option>
    <option value="Copper flat" data-min-width="10" data-max-width="200" data-min-thickness="1" data-max-thickness="20">Copper flat</option>
    <option value="Fabricated Copper Busbar" data-min-width="40" data-max-width="150" data-min-thickness="2" data-max-thickness="5">Fabricated Copper Busbar</option>
    <option value="Fabricated aluminium Busbar" data-min-width="3" data-max-width="20" data-min-thickness="1" data-max-thickness="9">Fabricated aluminium Busbar</option>
  </select>

  Width: <input type="number" id="width" required />
  
  thickness: <input type="number" id="thickness" required />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```